# jquery multiple external domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, dns, external

I would like to take this script and have it filter
an array of domains. The client has multiple domains
and all are considered "internal". Any thoughts?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#extlinks a').filter(function() {
 return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
  }).after(' <img src="/images/external.png" alt="external link"/>');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an array of valid domains and check whether `$.inArray(this.hostName, validDomains) < 0`.
[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).